# Cannot connect to JAMS server other than localshost

Tags: c#

I am trying to control/run JAMS from a C# application. Most of the examples I have checked only connect to `localhost`, but I am trying to connect to a remote server through my program to use JAMSShr assembly.

I current am doing the following, which works great:

```
JAMS.Server js = JAMS.Server.GetServer("localhost");
```

I'm trying this to connect to the remote server:

```
JAMS.Server js = JAMS.Server.GetServer("JAMS_SCHED.PEER1.Company.COM");
```

I have username and password setup in JAMS.

Comment: This is a little vague. Are you sure the server accepts remote connections? Also, what's `JAMS`? Is it some sort of technology/library? If so, include it as a tag.

Comment: Do you get an exception? Please edit your question (look for the link at the bottom of it) to share that information with us. Without that information, it is hard to help you. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: JAMS is a 3rd party scheduling software we use in our company.http://www.jamsscheduler.com/

Comment: I can't create a tag unless I have like some superhuman reputation of 1500+.I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure their is an entry in host file to resolve your server name to IP address.
Also make sure API versions are compatible with version of JAMS server you are using.They are not very compatible.